# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test/ Unit Root test on multiple time series dataframe in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset/dataframe in which I have calculated the daily log returns of five thousand companies and these companies are as column as well. I want carry out ADF test on this dataframe. I have found how to estimate ADF test on vector but could not find how to calculate it on dataframe or matrix structure. Additionally how can I leave out the date column when estimating ADF test on the companies.

```
structure(list(Price.Date..1. = structure(c(10961, 10962, 10963, 
10966, 10967, 10968, 10969, 10970, 10973, 10974, 10975, 10976, 
10977, 10980, 10981, 10982, 10983, 10984, 10987, 10988, 10989, 
10990, 10991, 10994, 10995, 10996, 10997, 10998, 11001, 11002, 
11003, 11004, 11005, 11008, 11009, 11010, 11011, 11012, 11015, 
11016, 11017, 11018, 11019, 11022, 11023, 11024, 11025, 11026, 
11029, 11030, 11031, 11032, 11033, 11036, 11037, 11038, 11039, 
11040, 11043, 11044, 11045, 11046, 11047, 11050, 11051, 11052, 
11053, 11054, 11057, 11058, 11059, 11060, 11061, 11064, 11065, 
11066, 11067, 11072, 11073, 11074, 11075, 11079, 11080, 11081, 
11082, 11085, 11086, 11087, 11088, 11089, 11092, 11093, 11094, 
11095, 11096, 11099, 11100, 11101, 11102, 11103), class = "Date"), 
    A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...S. = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.172842812839411, 0.0105264129869873, -0.0105264129869873, 
    0.0312525435041042, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0103093696588612, 0, 
    0.0505157901369016, 0.154854162093344, -0.0127390257774298, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0215991118034617, 0, -0.0310446216819606, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00896866998276025, -0.00896866998276025, 0.0695932917991957, 
    0.0491902441907719, 0, 0, 0, 0.0237165266173154, -0.0645385211375711, 
    0, 0.00829880281469553, -0.0208775850215552, -0.0475251418628453, 
    0, 0, -0.0406376457318265, -0.0233110788684474, -0.00947874395454384, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0588405000229333, 0, 0, -0.0101523714640175, 
    0, 0, -0.119059360015989, -0.0115608224010764, -0.0537442760066904, 
    0, 0, 0, -0.0185763855729357, 0, 0, 0, -0.0125787822068597, 
    -0.0997504027670599, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0212022076506022, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0143887374520997, 
    -0.0597192347016229, 0, 0, -0.0553500950831642, 0), ABACUS.GROUP.DEAD...18.02.09...S. = c(-0.00772204609391025, 
    0.0153849188394792, 0, 0, 0, 0.0121397545506108, 0.00751318335078377, 
    0, 0.0467921615067581, 0.00427655676726069, 0.00284091100160389, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.00284091100160389, -0.00427655676726069, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0974553361507127, -0.0126784582597708, 
    -0.00319489089651892, 0.0190180058357612, 0.0248074737042678, 
    0.0331355615960991, -0.00148257996022316, 0, -0.00744605078407812, 
    0, -0.00599701947237463, -0.00301205046999176, 0.00301205046999176, 
    0, 0.0527208463787359, 0, 0, 0.0554927382614965, 0.0147356986537535, 
    0, 0, -0.0255906220631887, -0.0109740470319766, 0.0204785313435405, 
    0.0266682470821618, 0.00655740054615883, 0, -0.013158084577511, 
    -0.0405460943943501, -0.00692044284457349, 0, -0.0210534091978323, 
    -0.00426439878645812, 0.136908873392753, 0.00371978110253224, 
    0, 0, -0.0012383902511468, -0.046933153422219, -0.00390371348047402, 
    -0.0065402456806094, -0.00922880643762181, -0.0200675630508096, 
    0.00269905696916517, 0.0147159846325131, 0.00265252144913131, 
    0.00264550418842369, 0, 0, -0.00662692948760846, -0.0504537812558326, 
    0.0138891121606672, 0.0204785313435405, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.0067340321813445, 0.0133335308694651, 0.00264550418842369, 
    0.00658330224919812, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.054895721731917, 
    -0.00873367996875452, 0, -0.0012539186595939), ABB.R..IRS....S. = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ABBEY.NATIONAL.DEAD...T.O.SEE.702853...S. = c(-0.0167894814765495, 
    0.00738010729762184, -0.0116218952059857, 0.00529942946649875, 
    -0.0632708260597079, -0.0204785313435405, -0.0197336641569503, 
    -0.0225261451329324, -0.0428724565924723, -0.0369704309185455, 
    -0.00913248356327223, -0.0442134971420201, 0.0468312996840989, 
    -0.0291797891087766, -0.00810815252842279, 0.052852458178311, 
    0.0291713773002797, -0.038221212820198, -0.0303253297149118, 
    -0.0382038274117704, 0.00554786443771782, 0.0123712918025465, 
    -0.0840351843165834, -0.00297619267304583, -0.0089820963158278, 
    -0.0151518050206025, 0.0433226819872985, -0.0433226819872985, 
    -0.032586281198026, 0.0202973400636752, 0.0289433760394884, 
    0.0681917498739066, 0.0180685944104999, -0.0166670524852117, 
    -0.0893058330631531, 0.00762780204888625, -0.0184054275427155, 
    -0.0203290816384261, 0.0187798946515967, 0.0974221130074682, 
    0, -0.0416427719597783, 0.00584796988242253, -0.0554449110217945, 
    -0.00773399059973645, 0.00155159069141853, 0.00618239990831793, 
    -0.0186630611319272, -0.0238295628329839, 0.0501672587180195, 
    0.0404549546923132, 0.104479070030021, -0.00663572441539895, 
    0.00464962644376943, -0.0120001440031103, 0.0649157135730478, 
    -0.0293388390059404, 0.0729977860835476, 0.00420294824644163, 
    0.0370521654605449, 0.00403342523190275, -0.0495092265431198, 
    -0.00302572091653719, 0.0386377927054138, 0.0902616769864686, 
    -0.0792438792460217, -0.0532985817243619, -0.0184167267862305, 
    -0.00621506040343434, 0.00435459475051392, -0.0302480527554971, 
    -0.0154741965825975, -0.0250013022054176, -0.0161185491020817, 
    -0.00747540008478342, 0.00544219030268511, 0.00135593241113607, 
    0.0559909153550144, -0.0122463663921577, -0.0471378335218366, 
    -0.00545331958131356, 0.0395361374015071, -0.0239373131439269, 
    0.0421669846355881, -0.034124045836128, 0.0347689990993745, 
    0.0279738520424058, -0.0157981168765913, 0.0424003660706616, 
    0.0121360712822254, 0.0244277859766919, 0.0375441148948044, 
    -0.0698435733672644, 0.00847462699097257, -0.0551393918480914, 
    0.0362766482201318, 0.0266682470821618, 0.0312065358208127, 
    0.0274459766087478, -0.000564174909181148), ABBEY.PROTECTION.DEAD...20.01.14...S. = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...S. = c(0, 
    0, 0.0326559629740526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.01619468591998, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0164612770540726, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -0.00833338155914376, -0.00840341079637952, 0, -0.00847462699097257, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.00854706057845789, 
    -0.00862074304390781, 0, 0, 0.0340458414097178, -0.00840341079637952, 
    0, 0, -0.00847462699097257, -0.00854706057845789, 0, 0, -0.00862074304390781, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0130720815673522, 0, 0, 0, -0.0221738574943222, 
    0, 0.00892863074430128, 0, 0, 0, -0.00892863074430128, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00892863074430128, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ABBOT.GROUP.DEAD...07.03.08...S. = c(-0.00470589103741315, 
    0.0550597771830272, 0.0393924017106615, 0.02542509836581, 
    0.0124741742251757, 0, 0, -0.0208775850215552, 0, -0.00847462699097257, 
    -0.0302398851897179, -0.0221738574943222, 0, 0.0265502320941211, 
    -0.00877198607283702, -0.0088496152769828, -0.00892863074430128, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, -0.02267670867103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0138570346614264, 
    -0.0140517534556501, -0.0190481949706944, -0.00966191091173663, 
    -0.00975617494536518, -0.0198026272961789, -0.0943106794712421, 
    0.0163491380015302, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0218587938124992, 0.0218587938124992, 
    0.0779615414697119, 0.00995033085316788, 0, -0.0200006667066699, 
    0, 0.010050335853502, 0.00995033085316788, 0.0530244683082204, 
    -0.038282186571017, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0147422817372034, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -0.00496278934212935, -0.00498754151103853, -0.0151136378100487, 
    0, -0.0153455696746603, -0.0208340869028421, 0, -0.0105821093305369, 
    0, 0.0262482260749364, -0.0104167608582557, 0, -0.037337670437644, 
    0.0215062052209634, 0.0210534091978323, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.025708356710207, 
    0, 0.03980625040042, 0, 0, -0.0098040000966213, 0, -0.0557106070140057, 
    -0.0104712998672953, -0.0159154553058993, 0, 0.0315815720502988, 
    0, 0.0103093696588612, -0.00514139950041859, 0, 0, -0.0208340869028421, 
    0.0156661167443994, -0.0104167608582557), ABBOTT.LABS.GBP..LON..DEAD...DEAD...S. = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...S. = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("Price.Date..1.", 
"A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...S.", "ABACUS.GROUP.DEAD...18.02.09...S.", 
"ABB.R..IRS....S.", "ABBEY.NATIONAL.DEAD...T.O.SEE.702853...S.", 
"ABBEY.PROTECTION.DEAD...20.01.14...S.", "ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...S.", 
"ABBOT.GROUP.DEAD...07.03.08...S.", "ABBOTT.LABS.GBP..LON..DEAD...DEAD...S.", 
"ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...S."), row.names = c("4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "83", 
"84", "85", "86", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", 
"96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", 
"106"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you want to carry out one ADF test for each company, i.e. 5000 tests all together, or only one test for all companies together? And could you please give us a small piece of the dataframe, perhaps 5 columns and a reasonable number of rows? You can use `dput` for that purpose.

Comment: @mra68 I apologize for the vague description and adding the image of small portion of my dataset. You have asked an excellent question I wanted to carry out ADF test fr each company i.e. 5000 test all together. But I would also want to know how to carry out one test for all companies.

Comment: One test for each company is what I was hoping for. Actually I don't know much about these tests. In particular not, if a test with "vector-valued" random variables (dimension 5000 in this case) makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to run one test for each column.
At [this link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) you can find a description of `apply`.
If "date" is the first column of the data.frame `df` then `df[,-1]` is that data.frame without the "date" column:

```
library(tseries)

#----------------------------------------------------------------
# example data:

set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(NA,300,5)

for ( i in 1:ncol(X))
{
  X[,i] <- sample(-100:100,nrow(X),replace=TRUE) / 1000
}

df <- cbind( date = as.Date("2015-01-01") + (1:nrow(X))*as.difftime(1,units="days"),
             as.data.frame(X) )

#----------------------------------------------------------------

a = "stationary"
lagOrder = trunc((nrow(df)-1)^(1/3))

Test <- apply(df[,-1],2,adf.test, alternative=a, k=lagOrder )
```

Result:

```
> Test <- apply(df[,-1],2,adf.test, alternative=a, k=lagOrder )
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
3: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
4: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
5: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
> Test
$V1

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  newX[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = -6.9796, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$V2

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  newX[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = -6.6985, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$V3

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  newX[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = -6.5085, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$V4

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  newX[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = -6.9839, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$V5

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  newX[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = -7.0185, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

I'm not sure where the warnings come from. Perhaps my example data is not reasonable. `Test[n]` is the test for the n-th company.

Missing values (`NA`) in a column `x` might be a problem. If `x` is replaced by `na.omit(x)` then the time series is no longer equidistant. One idea is to fill the `NA`-gaps by interpolation. In the following example, we use linear interpolation:

```
library(tseries)

#----------------------------------------------------------------
# example data:

set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(NA,300,5)

for ( i in 1:ncol(X))
{
  X[,i] <- sample(-100:100,nrow(X),replace=TRUE) / 1000
}

for ( i in 1:ncol(X))
{
  X[sample(1:nrow(X),floor(nrow(X)/10),replace=FALSE),i] <- NA
}

df <- cbind( date = as.Date("2015-01-01") + (1:nrow(X))*as.difftime(1,units="days"),
             as.data.frame(X) )

#----------------------------------------------------------------

a = "stationary"
lagOrder = trunc((nrow(df)-1)^(1/3))


Test <- apply(df[,-1], 2,
              function(x){
                tryCatch(
                  {
                    n <- which.max(!is.na(x))
                    m <- nrow(df)-which.max(!is.na(rev(x)))+1
                    return(adf.test(approx(n:m,x[n:m],xout=n:m)$y, alternative=a, k=lagOrder ))
                  },
                  error = function(e)
                  {
                    message(e)
                    writeLines("")
                    return(NA)
                  } )
                }
              )
```

Example data with missing values:

```
> head(df,15)
         date     V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
1  2015-01-02 -0.047     NA  0.063  0.067 -0.027
2  2015-01-03 -0.026 -0.081  0.086     NA  0.049
3  2015-01-04  0.015 -0.001 -0.071 -0.046     NA
4  2015-01-05  0.082 -0.008  0.050 -0.063  0.035
5  2015-01-06 -0.060 -0.025  0.096 -0.055  0.040
6  2015-01-07  0.080  0.099  0.095 -0.088  0.070
7  2015-01-08     NA -0.065 -0.030 -0.088  0.041
8  2015-01-09  0.032  0.063 -0.021 -0.071  0.072
9  2015-01-10  0.026 -0.087  0.091 -0.086 -0.011
10 2015-01-11 -0.088 -0.020 -0.079     NA     NA
11 2015-01-12 -0.059 -0.072  0.087  0.005 -0.075
12 2015-01-13 -0.065 -0.062 -0.031     NA  0.047
13 2015-01-14  0.038  0.069  0.007  0.039     NA
14 2015-01-15 -0.023     NA     NA     NA     NA
15 2015-01-16  0.054 -0.047  0.043 -0.097 -0.018
```

Result:

```
> Test
$V1

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -6.5244, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$V2

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -6.4918, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$V3

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -6.519, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$V4

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -7.2095, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$V5

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -7.2067, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


>
```

Example using the data given in the question:

```
> a = "stationary"

> lagOrder = trunc((nrow(df)-1)^(1/3))

> Test <- apply(df[,-1], 2,
+               function(x){
+                 tryCatch(
+                   {
+                     n <- which.max(!is.na .... [TRUNCATED] 
need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
Warning messages:
1: In adf.test(approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y, alternative = a,  :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
2: In adf.test(approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y, alternative = a,  :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
3: In adf.test(approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y, alternative = a,  :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
4: In adf.test(approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y, alternative = a,  :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
5: In adf.test(approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y, alternative = a,  :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
>
```

Result:

```
> Test
$A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...S.

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -4.4222, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$ABACUS.GROUP.DEAD...18.02.09...S.

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -6.4671, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$ABB.R..IRS....S.
[1] NA

$ABBEY.NATIONAL.DEAD...T.O.SEE.702853...S.

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -4.4337, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$ABBEY.PROTECTION.DEAD...20.01.14...S.
[1] NA

$ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...S.

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -5.7007, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$ABBOT.GROUP.DEAD...07.03.08...S.

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  approx(n:m, x[n:m], xout = n:m)$y
Dickey-Fuller = -4.5546, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary


$ABBOTT.LABS.GBP..LON..DEAD...DEAD...S.
[1] NA

$ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...S.
[1] NA

> which(is.na(Test))
                            ABB.R..IRS....S. 
                                           3 
       ABBEY.PROTECTION.DEAD...20.01.14...S. 
                                           5 
      ABBOTT.LABS.GBP..LON..DEAD...DEAD...S. 
                                           8 
ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...S. 
                                           9 
>
```

Comment: > library(tseries)
a = "stationary"
lagOrder = trunc((nrow(logs)-1)^(1/3))    I ran the test as this and received the error Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs in x                           Sorry,I'm still learning how to give r output and dput() in the post and comments and you see I'm failing miserably. Your help is highly appreciated

Test <- apply(logs[,-1],2,adf.test, alternative=a, k=lagOrder )

Comment: How to deal with missing values in the Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test is another question, perhaps even a good question. But it is more likely a question for mathematicians, not for R programmers.

Comment: @mra60  I ran the code again as       library(tseries)
logs <- cbind( Date = as.Date("2015-01-01") + (1:nrow(logs))*as.difftime(1,units="days"),
             as.data.frame(logs) )
a="stationarity"
Test <- apply(logs[,-1],2,adf.test, alternative=a, k=lagOrder )                       but received the error  Error in match.arg(alternative) : 
  'arg' should be one of “stationary”, “explosive”

Comment: This is just a typo. Replace "stationarity" by "stationary". Or remove `alternative=a`, since "stationary" is the default value.

Comment: I enhanced my answer by an idea how to remove the missing values.

Comment: I received this  Error in if (interpol == min(tablep)) warning("p-value smaller than printed p-value") else warning("p-value greater than printed p-value") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: can you please explain this df <- cbind( date = as.Date("2015-01-01") + (1:nrow(X))*as.difftime(1,units="days"),
             as.data.frame(X) )    why this being added. I have high hopes from you mra68

Comment: `as,data.frame` turns the matrix `X` into a data.frame. Then `cbind` is used to add the "date"-column. But this is not important at all. I just used it to build some example data. You should run the second part of the script (below the `#------------------` line with `df` replaced by your dataframe. The warnings about the p-value can be ignored, I guess. There is a question/answer on StackOverflow about this issue.

Comment: When you replace my example dataframe `df` by your dataframe and receive error messeges, I cannot say anything about it, if I do not have your data. If the dataframe is too large, you can perhaps use an upload service and add a link to you question.

Comment: I do understand it's bit of a stretch but kindly can you explain how can I use dput () and limit the no. of rows and columns because my dataset has 4998(companies )    columns and about 3798(daily observation,date) rows to produce a reproducible example.  Thank you for your patience!

Comment: `df1 <- df[1:200,1:10]` will give you the first 200 rows and the first 10 columns of the dataframe `df` and store it in a dataframe `df1`. Now type `dput(df1)` on the console, copy the output from the console, and paste it into your question. Mark it as code, if possible.

Comment: Thank you I have added some portion of my data here, actually I took 100 rows the data is massive. I would like to add here these values in the company columns are daily log returns, which were calculated as 'logs=data.frame(cbind.data.frame(Date$Price[-1],diff(as.matrix(log(Price[,-1])))))'  Price was the name of my df

Comment: Some columns contained **only** `NA`. But after removing them the test was successful. I added the test to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But actually my data is has a sample period of 2000 to 2014. And the companies included in it are the ones that had been and are listed/its stocks being traded at London Stock Exchange for 2000-2014. So, if you look at the company ABS R (IRS) (#S) it has NA because it was listed/its stock started trading in year 2002. If you could help me develop a code like the one where I could give TRUE/FALSE to tge missing value. But I realize you have helped alot ready, if you don't have time for such code just let me know I will accept your answer.

Comment: If you use **all** rows, not just the first 100 as in the example data, then you do not have to remove those rows. Did you try? By the way: You are saying yourself that I have helped you a lot. I have answered your original question completely and correctly, and even did a little bit extra stuff. But there is still a "0" next to my answer. Isn't it time to click on the upward arrow above that "0" or even the checkmark? You should give credit if you get a correct answer, not only if all your problems are solved.

Comment: Honestly I clicked 1 to your answer that is to rank it up yesterday but my reputation is only 12 I have to wait till I have a reputation of 15 to rank up the answers. I highly acknowledge your answer and efforts.

Comment: And yes I have ran the code as you developed but get still get this error Error: unexpected symbol in "Test <- apply(logs[,-1], 2,function(x){n <- which.max(!is.na(x))m"

Comment: What is the unexpected symbol? There should be a line break between "which.max(!is.na(x))" and "m". Did you use a script as in the answer, or did you try to write everything in one line on the console?

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I think I messed up with line break, I'm new to programming. Could you please put the final code again here in the comments which starts from library(tseries) a="stationary" . As you mentioned I don't need to remove the NA. This post 'R Error with ADF test in Time Series Lapply' is very close to my case.

Comment: The code is still contained in the answer. I recommend to use a script file. Create an empty text file "script.R", copy the code from the answer and paste it into the text file. If "path" is the full path to the file "script.R", type "source(path)" on the console. Or use R Studio. That makes it even easier.

Comment: I wish I could send my data set to you, you are my only hope :D @mra68

Comment: Did you succeed in writing a script file? If not, what was the problem?

Comment: I copy pasted the code for the example in which you created data by yourself, I did not include the coding under # example I copied library(tseries) and then started froma="stationary"it in the script file. Received 'Error in if (interpol == min(tablep)) warning("p-value smaller than printed p-value") else warning("p-value greater than printed p-value") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed '

Comment: What if you copy the entire code into the script file and then run the script? Do you get the same output as in the answer?

Comment: Yes I ran same exact code as well and I got the results as printed by you here. But when I run it on my own data no luck.

Comment: If `data` is the name of your dataframe, insert `df <- data[,1:3]` right before `a<-"stationary"`. If you still get an error messege, try `df<-data[1:m,1:3]` for various numbers "m". At least m=100 should work. Then increase "m".

Comment: Hurrah! with this addition it gave me ADF test results for the first two companies. Test is being created under Value section of Environment and it List of 2. Can you please make addition for all companies, pretty please!

Comment: Replace `df <- data[,1:3]` by `df <- data[,1:n]` for various numbers "n" and find the number "n" for which the error messege first occurs. Then look at the n-th column of you dataframe. You can also check the n-th column on its own by using `df <- data[,c(1,n)]`

Comment: so, what should I do with this nth company, I have got an output

Comment: Look if there is something suspicious. For example, check how many non-`NA` values are in there: `sum(!is.na(data[,n]))`. Or try if the n-th column still works if only "m" rows are used: `df <- data[1:m,c(1,n)]`. Choose "m" large enough to have enough non-`NA`'s in there. Then increase "m" until the error occurs and look at `data[m,n]`.

Comment: What if I exclude this nth company and run on rest. Can you please tell how can I exclude that nth company. Why can't I just increase the number of companies/columns in df <- data[,1:3]. And the result for sum(!is.na(data[,n])) is 216. Kindly guide me for the next step

Comment: Use `df <- data[,-n]` to exclude the "n"-th column. If you want to exclude two columns "n1" and "n2", use `df<-data[,-c(n1,n2)]`, and so on. But I'm getting hungry and will switch of my computer now. Happy new year!

Comment: I'm working on it according to your suggestion. Thank you, you saved me from crying all night on new year's eve. Happy new year.

Comment: I have edited my answer again. The function that is called in `apply` now contains a `tryCatch` block to catch the errors. There will still be errors, but they won't stop the calculation. If an error occurs, the corresponting component in `Test` will be `NA` instead of the result from the `adf.test`-function. After running the script, `which(is.na(Test))` will show you the columns that caused an error. The other entries in `Test` will contain the `adf.test`-result.

Comment: I ran this code that you updated,even I add library (tseries) in the start of the code but strangely I get error 'could not find function "adf.test". But suggestion in which you said to add df <- data [,1:3]. I played around and when I add df <- data [,1:8] I get the results for first seven companies.

Comment: Insert the line `print(paste0("Does adf.test exist? ",exists("adf.test")))` right before `return(adf.test(...))`. Is the answer `TRUE` at least for the first few columns? And does the error stop the calculation immediately? That shouldn't be the case.You can check this as follows: In the function `error` replace `message(e)` by `message(paste0("catched error: ",e))`. The error "could not find function adf.test" doesn't stop the calculation if and only if it is a "catched error".

Comment: No luck :(        receive error "Does adf.test exist? FALSE"
could not find function "adf.test"

Comment: If it works for `df <- data[,1:8]`, how about `df <- data[,1:9]`, `df <- data[,1:10]` and so on? And was the error catched or not?

Comment: df<- data[,1:9] and so on adding 1:10 or 1:11 doesn't give any output. No errors were catched

Comment: How does the reasulting `Test` look like when you use the first 10 columns. Better remove `Test` before the calculation: Insert `rm(Test)` right before `Test <- apply(...)`.

Comment: Yes I removed it by rm(Test) and ran it for 1:10 but only a="stationary" gets created again.

Comment: Yes again this one  Error in if (interpol == min(tablep)) warning("p-value smaller than printed p-value") else warning("p-value greater than printed p-value") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: And what was the answer to "Does ad.test exist?"?

Comment: That came like this [1]"Does adf.test exist? FALSE"
could not find function "adf.test"

Comment: Only once, or seven times "TRUE" and then "FALSE"?

Comment: Hurrah! I got result for 9 compnaies and  this [1] "Does adf.test exist? TRUE"
[1] "Does adf.test exist? TRUE"
[1] "Does adf.test exist? TRUE"
[1] "Does adf.test exist? TRUE"
[1] "Does adf.test exist? TRUE"
[1] "Does adf.test exist? TRUE"
[1] "Does adf.test exist? TRUE"
[1] "Does adf.test exist? TRUE"
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
[1] "Does adf.test exist? TRUE"
variable lengths differ (found for 'yt1')

Comment: Are the errors catched or not? Are `NA`s in `Test` where the errors occur? And what if you use `df <- data[,1:n]` with "n" increasing?

Comment: Yes two companies had NA under the Augmented Dickey Fuller Test result. n increasing means?

Comment: Replace `df <- data[,1:10]` by `df <- data[,1:30]`, `df <- data[,1:100]`,..., for example.

Comment: Hurrah! I ran for [,1:4998] and received Test as list of 4997 elements. But Error and Warnings included 'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed', 'wrong embedding dimension'. And what should I do for the companies who have NA as result of ADF test. Because I have to prove that in sample all series are stationary.

Comment: First of all, I would check how many companies caused an error: `sum(which(is.na(Test)))`. The erroneous companies are listed in `E <- Test[which(is.na(Test))]`. If "n" is one of the numbers in `E`, then `data[,n+1]` is the timeseries for that company (`n+1` instead of `n`, because the time column was omitted.) Perhaps there is simply not enough data.  I would plot the timeseries and compare it to those, for which the calculation was successful: `plot(data[,n+1],type="l")` ((l)ines). But perhaps it is simply impossible to prove anything. Then try to "prove" **why** it is nearly impossible.

Comment: okie I work on it according to your suggestion. And mra68 I have to run KPSS test on this same data frame as well. I will post the question,so, could you answer that as well and I will accept your answer because the thing is you have now greater understanding of my dataset.

Comment: There is no need to post another question. I'm afraid it would be marked as "duplicate" anyway. Just replace `adf.test` by the function for the KPSS test. Perhaps the KPSS test works for the companies that failed the ADF test.

Comment: Although KPSS and ADF serve the same function but have different hypothesis and in tseries they have slightly different specification.

Comment: The general pattern will be the same. The function that is called by `apply` contains the application of the test function to a single timeseries.

Comment: could you please help me carry out Durbin Watson test, I have posted a question. I would really apprecaite your help